# Which is the better way to store images for the plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, images

I have been developing a plugin and I am confused at the moment whether to store in wordpress upload folder or my plugin folder. I will be storing image in custom table.I also got another technique to store image in blob format. Will I be able to store directly into database without uploading?

Comment: not sure what is the question here... the gut feeling is that it is wrong, but that fully depends on what is it that your plugin does and how it does it.

Comment: I need to store logos of the companies.

Comment: and why using the wordpress media API not good enough?

Comment: No. The logo will be related to company custom table.

Comment: I dont want the images to stay if the plugin is uninstalled. So better would be store in custom table.

Answer (score 3):

The only directory in which you have guaranteed write access is the uploads directory. Even your plugin's directory might be write protected, the same for `wp-content` (which doesn't even have to exist).

Comment: Is it possible to store in blob format in database like this one https://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/how-to-store-and-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database/

Comment: please edit your question to make it a complete question with the full scenario, and avenues you have researched

Answer (score -1):

If there are only few images which are required for the plugin itself then store it under plugins own image folder. If you are making something else; where user will upload its own data then safely use uploads folder.